# Change the ContentPage's content with customize titleview

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabs, customization, page-title, content-pages

I make a customize title in the titleview,
and I want to show different content(with other pages) by pressing the tabs I customize.(like pic shows below)
I am wondering how to change the content with different pages...

```
    <ContentPage>
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Button x:Name="energy" />
    <Button x:Name="history" />
    ...
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <ContentPage.Content>
//when I press energy, and content shows the Energy.xaml
//when I press history, and content shows the History.xaml
    </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: this really defeats the purpose of using a NavigationPage.  If you just want to have tabs at the top of the page there are better ways to do it.

Comment: What you want to achieve is more like a [tabbed-page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TabView` from `XamarinCommunityToolkit` package, here is a sample page you can find it in their sample repo.

```xml
<ContentPage  xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
...
>
  <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <xct:TabView
                TabStripBackgroundColor="Blue"
                TabStripHeight="40"
                TabIndicatorColor="Yellow"
                TabContentBackgroundColor="Yellow">
                <xct:TabViewItem
                    Text="Tab 1"
                    TextColor="White"
                    TextColorSelected="Yellow"
                    FontSize="12">
 <--Here you define the content of Tab1 -->
                </xct:TabViewItem>
                <xct:TabViewItem
                    Text="Tab 2"
                    TextColor="White"
                    TextColorSelected="Yellow"
                    FontSize="12">
 <--Here you define the content of Tab2 : it can be the ContentView defined in your Energy.xaml -->
                </xct:TabViewItem>
            </xct:TabView>
        </Grid>
  <ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

There is plenty of stuff you can customize take a look at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview).